# Reuse error tableView with cell design programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with my tableView who I managed specially, i need to delete and add row really often. My cell are designed programmatically. I update my array who depend my cells and called `self.tableView.reloadData()` but this don't remove the cells I need and update the tableView like my array.

Cause to the reuse and my design of cell (programmatically) I need to check if the cell is always design or not. And the problem come from here.

When I called `tableView.reloadData()` my data are not properly reload, so I need to delete All view in the cells: indicate that the cells are not design, to design the new cell ... Of course I can just update the visible cells (with `tableView.visibleCells`), so this work but **how can I update my other not-visible cells ?**

Maybe I have an architecture problem? If so, what is the best way to delete and insert a row in the TableView with a indexPath defined? Or, how programmatically design the cell only one time?

Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return user.lobbySurvey.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"Celll") as! CardCell
    for survey in user.lobbySurvey{
        let index = user.lobbySurvey.index(where: {
            //get the current index is nedeed else the cells reuse lazy
            $0 === survey
        })
        if indexPath.row == index{
            var surveyState : UserSurvey.state
            surveyState = survey.state
            switch surveyState{
            case .selectSurvey:
                cell.drawCard(statutOfCard: .selectSurvey)
            case .goSurvey:
                cell.drawCard(statutOfCard: .goSurvey(picture: survey.picture))
            case .surveyEnded:
                print("survey Ended")
            case .surveyWork:
                print("survey in progress to vote")
            case .surveyWaiting:
                cell.drawCard(statutOfCard: .surveyWaiting(selfSurveyId: survey.id, timeLeft: survey.timeLeft, picture: survey.picture))
            case .buyStack:
                cell.drawCard(statutOfCard: .buyStack(supView : self.view))
            }
        }
    }

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.delegateCard = self
    cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
    tableView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    return cell
}
```

Comment: **_"how can I update my other not-visible cells ?"_** You don't need to. Just update your data source which will reflect the changes once the cells become visible.

Comment: can you share your code that is responsible for reloading data in tableview and updating data in array

Comment: Did you override prepareForReuse() in your cell in order to reset the cell's view? Please post snippets of code from relevant sections, like numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri yes but when I update my data source the design of the old cell who have the old same row index stay here

Comment: You should only call `reloadData` if the whole array has changed. If you have changed a specific row, call `reloadRows` and then your `cellForRowAt` can take care of updating the cell. Cells that aren't on screen will be ignored until they are

Comment: @El-Burritos design your cell in `cellForRowAt`. It should show your the proper design if you update your data source and reload the table.

Comment: @HafizShoaibAwan I edit my post for the code

Comment: @RakeshaShastri this is what I do but not work ...

Comment: Thank all to your reply. My problem is I reload my tableView without reflection. I delete my row properly and add it properly and now it's work, I post the code who resolved my problem next hour

Comment: So i'm not resolve my problem I have a problem with my cell. I think a go to create different type of cell instead of 1 who have different design...

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array which is the model of your table:

`NSMutableArray *model;` (model can have identifier).

You can change this model whenever you want.

With this you can make your table dynamic just calling `tableView.reloadData()` and make whatever in `cellForRow` & `heightForRow`

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat height;
    YourModel *model = self.model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[SomeClassTableViewCellModel class]]) {
        height = 50;
    } else if([model.identifier isEqualToString:@"Whatever"]){
        height = 0.0f;
    else{
        height = kHeightForNormalCells;
    }
    return height;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   YourModel *model = self.model[indexPath.row];
   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:model.identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   if ([cell isKindOfClass:[SomeClass class]]) {
       NSLog(@"Configure Cell");
       [cell setModel:model];
   }
   return cell;
}
```

Moreover, your cell should have a method setModel:

```
- (void)setModel:(SomeTableViewCellModel *)model {
   _model = model;
   self.label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",model.value1];
   self.label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",model.value2];
}
```

Hope this helps you.